# Chrome extension content scripts - Is the source available for users to see?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm creating a unique (haven't seen something similar) chrome extension that most of its code goes into its content script. I'm a little bit concerted that people would copy my code if they can view my content script js file. Can they? Is there anything to do about it?

Comment: Anyone who's knowledgeable enough to open devtools will see the code of all content scripts that run on the page. Anyone who can browse files on their computer, can inspect the entire source of all extensions they have.

Comment: So why don't people "steal"/copy from big apps like "AdBlock"? Doesn't most of the code for ad blocking go into the content scripts?

Comment: Who said they don't? AdBlock is opensource so everyone is free to copy its code as long as they do it according to the AdBlock license which is GPLv3 apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to secure it. But if you have license for your chrome extension and it's not an open source than you can claim on the person whoever steal/copy it. You can add note for do not copy content scripts. Also, you can do some stuff to protect content scripts like obfuscate of all your JavaScript, you can convert your content scripts into minified version.